# What are "bad" backlinks and how would I know which ones to remove?

Tags: seo, backlinks

My website had a drop in traffic and one SEO guy suggested to me that I should remove bad backlinks. Now I need to know what's considered a "bad" backlink, and how would I know which ones to remove?